# Question about Logistic Regression - Formula

Tags: regression, logistic

could someone help me. 
http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~jiali/course/stat597e/notes2/logit.pdf (page 4)
 What exactly are $\beta_{10}$ and $\beta_{20}$. How are they defined?

I don't understand this, it's stated that $\beta=(\beta_{10}, \beta_1)^{T}$

Comment: They are defined on page 4 of the slides. Can you clarify what exactly you do not understand about that slide? If this is self-study you need to add the self-study tag, read its wiki and tell us what your thoughts are.

Answer (score 1):

That is a multinomial logit model. The outcome has $K$ categories, one of which is the reference, so you are modeling $K-1$ odds. $\beta_{10}$ is the constant for the first odds, $\beta_{20}$ is the constant for the second odds, etc.